# Is there a complete non barrelled locally convex space?

Tags: general-topology, topological-vector-spaces, complete-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

[These answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/272064/barrelled-space) provides two examples of non [barrelled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrelled_space) locally convex spaces, but they are both incomplete.
Furthermore, their completion is a Banach space and so necessarily barrelled.

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2959318/is-the-space-of-bounded-continuous-functions-on-the-reals-with-the-topology-of-u) also presents an incomplete example (which is not normed), but its completion is also barrelled.

Is there any example of a complete, non barrelled, locally convex space?

*clarification:* By complete locally convex space I mean a space in which every Cauchy net converges (like in Kelley's General Topology p. 192).

Comment: What is your definition of a *complete* locally convex space?

Comment: A uniform space is complete if every Cauchy net converges. A locally convex space is complete if it is complete with the induced uniformity of the additive group.